# JAVA BufferedOutputStream flush slow with correct filesize

Tags: java, file, stream, operating-system, size

I am using a BufferedOutputStream to write to a file. While debugging I noticed that the flush operation takes very long even if the OS shows that the file has got the final size.

My theory:
The BufferedOutputStream tell the OS to reserve space in advance? So the OS already shows the file with the full filesize even if the BufferedOutputStream hasn't flushed completly?

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BufferedOutputStream` maintains its own internal `byte[]` buffer.  Looking at an [implementation of the code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#-WpwJU0UKqQ/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.java&q=BufferedOutputStream&l=38), it just fills that buffer before writing it to the underlying stream.  The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) doesn't give much more help.

I don't think you can make any more assumptions than this without looking at the native implementations on each platform.  If you wanted to get more details, you could run something like [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) and inspect what's happening for a simple program.

I wrote the following simple program

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("test.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 16384);
        for (int i=0;i<10000;++i) {
            bos.write(new byte[1024]);
        }
    }
}
```

And ran `strace` on it.  Make sure you use the `-f` flag to keep track of child processes.  A filtered copy of what ran is shown below.

```
[pid  6394] mprotect(0x7fdebc03e000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
[pid  6394] open("test.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 4
[pid  6394] fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  6394] mprotect(0x7fdebc03f000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
[pid  6394] write(4, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\"...,    16384) = 16384
[pid  6394] write(4, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\"...,    16384) = 16384
[pid  6394] write(4, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\"...,    16384) = 16384
```

I don't see any calls to reserve space up front (note entirely sure about [mprotect](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mprotect.html) but it doesn't seem relevant).  The behaviour I see on my Linux box is simply a buffer being filled and written to disk.

Comment: Okay, I am on Windows 7. I only want to be sure that this long time period is actually being used to do something. Not seeing the filesize changing for a few seconds, but the App hanging in the flush operation is making me worry.

Comment: Could it be that only the flush call will reserve space? bos.flush() is missing in your code. In the mean time I will look for some strace for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the case that your filesystem is remote and as such the call to flush passes the data through the network (and the host on the other side might decide to actually "reserve" the file space required as you put it and only write the bytes to disk once it has received all the bytes)? Or are you using a local filesystem?

Comment: What type of filesystem is it (NTFS, FAT/32, EXT3 etc)?

Comment: Hmmm... just a guess but I'd venture to say that you might have a hole in your filesystem -- have you tried  a scandisk on it? a flush shouldn't hang in there for so long unless there are probles with the filesystem and it takes the kernel too long to figure out on which sector to write the data or the file is really big -- how big is your file?

Comment: Files are 1Gig. But the problem was the virus scanner. Stupid thing was killing the performance

Answer (score 0):

Check your virus scanner. Sometimes that slows down file writes.